# Leave activity when back button pressed in fragment

Tags: android

I have an app with multiple activities, each of which may employ multiple fragments.

One activity (called IBAsTabsActivity) extends SherlockFragmentActivity and I am using some example code where a different fragment gets loaded up depending on which tab is selected. One of the possible fragments is called "SearchableListFragment". This is all working fine. I have a "home" activity with two buttons, one to take me to IBAsTabsActivity and another to take me to AnAlternativeActivity. If I press the button to take me to IBAsTabsActivity and look at several tabs - then if I press the back button I jump straight to "home".

Now I want to get AnAlternativeActivity up and running. It has no tabs and so does not employ any Sherlock code. Instead I have this:

```
public class AnAlternativeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blank_fragment_holder);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        SearchableListFragment fb = new SearchableListFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_holding_layout, fb);
        ft.addToBackStack("replacingFragmentA");
        ft.commit();
}
```

This all works fine in as much as if I click on the button on the home screen to call AnAlternativeActivity, then I see the SearchableListFragment() (inside fragment_holding_layout) and its contents correctly. But now if I click the back button the fragment within fragment_holding_layout disappears, but leaves AnAlternativeActivity still running. I have to press the back button again in order to exit AnAlternativeActivity and get back to my home activity.

I could probably cook up some ugly code to resolve this issue - but I suspect that there is a standard way to cope with this scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: your fragment.getActivity do what you want with that, call onBackPressed yourself

Comment: @Marko Lazić: could you expand on that?

Comment: cod3-monk-3y has a valid point.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the notion of parent-activity to resolve this easily. All you need to do is to tell Android that `HomeActivity` is the parent of your `AnAlternativeActivity` and the navigation will be handled by you. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file add `android:parentActivityName` attribute for `AnAlternativeActivity` like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.mick.AnAlternativeActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_title"
    android:parentActivityName="com.mick.HomeActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.mick.HomeActivity" />
</activity>
```

You need the regular attribute for new devices and meta-data tag for older devices. More information can be found here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html (look under **Add it to the manifest** subheading).

Comment: The compiler complained about android:parentActivityName - but accepted the meta-data. Then at run time it made no difference at all.

Comment: Are you running it on newer API? It may have got ignored. Also, look at this link, it shows all the code for proper navigation: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

Within AnAlternativeActivity's onPause you could call `finish()` to end it.

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: But then if the phone rings, you will be thrown out of that activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `ft.addToBackStack("replacingFragmentA");` seems to be the cause for the need for tapping 'Back' twice. Adding the transaction to the back stack will have that effect: adding a layer in the history stack.

So when you press 'Back' the first time that transaction will be 'undone' so to speak, and will replace your `SearchableListFragment` with the `R.id.fragment_holding_layout`. The second time you press 'Back' will move from the `AnAlternativeActivity` back to your 'home' activity.